# Can I edit data on oracle database automatically when client application closed by human operator?

Tags: sql, database, oracle10g

I have a client aplication work with a database on my server. That application insert/update a table on my database when human operator close application. I need to change some row of my table in database after application update/insert my table and closed.

How can i tell to oracle database execute procedure or trigger when application closed by human operators?

Oracle can understand time of a user close application that work with database? If yes, can i write job or trigger to run at that's time?
If no, have I choice to do that?

My Database: oracle 10g

Answer (score 1):

The trigger is an prcedure call automatically.
In the trigger, you make an AFTER UPDATE or INSERT or both statement.
Then you program the specific row you need to change.

After an insert for exemple Oracle execute the trigger and change the rows.

Hope it helps you a litte bit ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tested it, but my application edit my table continuously. If I wrote trigger to run after each table change, my process overhead increased.

Comment: What kind of language you use in you're application ? Maybe you can call a stored procedure in you're application. It's executive once and just when you call it.

Comment: I haven't access to sources.

Comment: Really ? It's too bad, if you're only access is the database then you don't have a choice. The only way is the triggers...

Answer (score 0):

You don't have specified much about Application (which is operated by human). And you can trigger procedure or execute procedure in oracle by handling appropriate event in Application (For example Application_End(), Form_Close() event in dot net).